# Draw route with Bing Maps on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am following (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681887.aspx) and I have three problems connected with assamblies I guess.

```
Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Location' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments
```

in

```
routeLine.Locations.Add(new Location(p.Latitude, p.Longitude));
```

And two other simmilar.

Can't find the issue as I have added good references...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong tutorial.
On Windows Phone you should use GeoCoordinate class. It has a constructor that accepts 2 arguments.

[Read more here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.aspx)

To use Bing Maps and route on Windows Phone, find [tutorial here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikebattista/archive/2011/01/18/geocoding-and-routing-with-bing-maps.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the links, but at the end I used BingMapsDirectionTask which is easy and pretty awesome!